# Convergence to 0 of product of $1-U_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $0<U_n<1$ be a sequence of decreasing numbers that converges to $0$. Let us consider $V_n$:
$$V_n = \prod_{k=0}^{n} (1-U_k)$$

Since $V_n$ is decreasing and lower bounded by $0$, we can conclude that it converges as $n$ tends to $\infty$. Let us write this limit $V_\infty$. **What would be a simple/minimal condition on $U_n$ to guarantee that $V_\infty > 0$ ?**

For instance, I already know that, if $U_n$ is upper bounded by a geometric sequence with ratio $r<1$ and initial value $a<1$, then:
$$ V_n \geq \prod_{k=0}^{n} (1-ar^n) = (a;r)_n,$$
with $(a;r)_n$ denoting the $q$-Pochhammer symbol. But I'm not even sure on the condition on $a$ and $r$ such that $(a;r)_\infty > 0$. It seems to me that it is always the case, but after some google search I've not found the information anywhere.

Comment: See, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2157322/convergence-of-infinite-products-definition

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product

Comment: (Also, welcome to this website, Maveric78f! I hope you'll find the above links useful.)